# 2 questions regarding Javascript & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at the code below. This function is used to add more text input when user click con a button. I don't understand 2 things.

1. Why we need this? `var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;` I don't understand what it is used for. I tested and see that the function still works as long as you define `var i`. I'm not sure if `$('#p_scents p').size() + 1;` is necessary here.
2. Why `return false;` in both 2 functions?

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The answer to your second question, if you're asking what `return false` within jQuery does, can be found here: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/691711)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;`

Above code must have made sense if you were using `var` `i` to give unique ID for dynamically added contents ,since the ID's should be always unique *(then you need to change the selector of size() too)*.

**Explanation :**

`size()` returns how many `#p_scents p` `(selector)` you have in page *(say 1)*

now you are adding `1` to it so `var i` becomes `2`
Now for the new input type text added by you is assigned by a unique name `"p_scnt_' + i +'"`  i.e. `p_scnt_2`.

So what I was telling is DOM should always have unique ID , therefore you should use `var i` value to give a unique ID .

Like this

```
$('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i +'" size="20" ...
```

In your code you have used `i` variable to give a unique `name`.

about `return false;` , its not at all required there since there is nothing in the code which you dont want to follow after `click` event.
You can use `return false` in an onclick event to stop the browser from processing the rest of the execution stack, which includes following the link in the href attribute.

Adding to that , you dont need to check `if( i > 2 ) {`  in remove button `click` because value will be always greater than `2` for every remove button on page.
Since at the time of adding a remove button dynamically you always increment `var i` value from `2`

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the size() function return?

Comment: @LouisTran : can you please read my answer again ,, its edited

Comment: Thank you, I understand that each field need a unique name and by this way we can create a unique ID for them. However, it doesn't make sense to me because the names are not consistent. The first field's name is `p_scnt` but the extra one starts from `p_scnt_2`. Why it starts from `2`? When you write a function to get data from these fileds. Its gonna add extra work instead of a loop start from `0` to `n`

Comment: the first name is `p_scnt` because that is the name you have given in the html... check your html sir .... there you have given ID `p_scnt ` .... and the next input you are adding from javascript and you are adding `var i ` value to new `p_scnt ` input ,,, so it next comes with `p_scnt _2` name

Comment: If you want it to be consistent , the input name in `HTML` should be `p_scnt _1` and not `p_scnt` ... so now the next will be `p_scnt_2`

Comment: I understand. This code is not mine. It comes from an expert who are better than me. I just don't understand why he wrote the code like that. Anyway, thank you very much for the details.

Comment: great ! .. I like the effort your making... you will also be an expert ..no doubt...and i think you are more smarter than your expert coder ... because you got him there..

Answer (score 1):

`i` looks to be tracking the number of items on the page. It's initialized to match how many items are on the page when it first loads. That's the purpose of `i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;`.

The `return false` causes the default behavior of the clicks to not occur. This is important, for example, if you have a click handler on a link, and you don't want clicking on them to go to the `href` of the link.